# Batch / REG QUERY get the path of found value

Tags: batch-file, regedit

I am trying to make a batch file, that finds a specific interface (their name vary from computer to computer = query). To find the interface I use a specific IP that is under that interface as a value.
The code here can find the interface in question based on the IP i insert into "IP-ADDRESS".

But my ultimate goal is to based on this search add two registry values into this interface, and therefore I need the path.

How do I get the path into a variable based on the search below?

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\ /s /f "IP-ADDRESS"') do set Myvar=%%b

ECHO %Myvar%
PAUSE
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure about the dash in `IP-ADDRESS` ? Also `"tokens=5*` doesn't seem right usually the 2nd is the type `REG_DWORD/_SZ/_MULTISZ`and the 3rd the value.

Comment: Ah yeah, token=5 is wrong, I was just experimenting, had 3 from the beginning, wrong copypaste.

Answer (score 0):

The following batch-file returns here:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\16\SO_53340832.cmd
IPADDRESS:192.168.56.1 on interface:{4fe80965-dda5-466a-801d-14937fd3829c}
```

It uses `"tokens=1,2*"` and /v `IPADDRESS` without dash.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\16\SO_53340832.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"
Set "Val=IPADDRESS"

For /f "tokens=1,2*" %%A in (
  'reg query "%Key%" /s /v "%Val%" ^| findstr /i "^HKEY %Val%"'
) Do if /i "%%A" neq "%Val%" (rem must be HKEY
    Set "Interface=%%A"
) Else (
    Echo %VAL%:%%C on interface:!Interface:%Key%\=!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RKP=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces"
Set "RVD=172.26.193.3"
Set "RKC="

For /F "Delims=}" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RKP%" /S /F "%RVD%" /D 2^>Nul'
) Do If Not Defined RKC Set "RKC=%%A}"

If Not Defined RKC Exit /B

Rem show the variable and value for five seconds
Set RKC
Timeout 5 >Nul
```